# Child class constructor - expected a '{'

Tags: c++, constructor, parent-child

I'm still learning C++ and some of the people here helped me a lot, thank you all.

I have another problem now : I have a class B derived from class A like this :

#### ClassB.h

```
#ifndef CLASSB
#define CLASSB

#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    #include "ClassA.h"
    
    class ClassA;
    
    class ClassB: public ClassA{
    
        public:
    
            ClassB(ClassC* classCinstance, int gnr, int type) : ClassA(classCinstance);
    };
    
    #endif
```

#### ClassB.cpp

```
#include "ClassB.h"

ClassB::ClassB(ClassC* classCinstance, int gnr, int type) : ClassA(classCinstance){
    //Some stuff
}
```

The problem is that when I compile, it says that :

> error C2969: syntax error : ';' : expected member function definition
> to end with '}'

And Visual Express tells me :

> Error: expected a '{'

when I point my cursor to the semicolon finishing line 18 in ClassB.h (the declaration of constructor of ClassB).

How can I solve that ? I declared this constructor so it exists... And I declare its body in the .cpp so... Everything's fine, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClassB constructor is bad declared:

```
ClassB(ClassC* classCinstance, int gnr, int type) : ClassA(classCinstance);
```

must be

```
ClassB(ClassC* classCinstance, int gnr, int type);
```

Comment: @Dennis, yes, you are rigth, It's not necesary, and, as you said, using namespaces inside .h is not a good practice. But, this is not the real problem.

Comment: The syntax you are using is meant for the Constructor definition, not the declaration. Put a `{}` before the `;` and it will work. However you also seem to have declared ClassA twice (once in the .h file) and once again immediately after including the .h file. Also don't put `using` in header files, as it will prevent re-use of your code by others who don't want to use those namespaces.

Comment: Yeah I agree. Just adding some useful info.

Comment: Now it tells me "error C2504: 'ClassA' : base class undefined" Does it come from the code of class A ?

Comment: @turbodoom, sorry, I don't use Visual, only g++. Try to delete `using namespace std;` and `ClassA` forward declaration. Show us the code line of error

Comment: @Tio Pepe this is what actually happends when I remove the forward declaration and `using namespace std;`

Comment: @turbodoom verify your ClassA.h file, maybe there is a type mismatch or class name confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of the constructor for `ClassB` in the header has a colon list, which it shouldn't. That's part of the *definition*.

So:

```
ClassB(ClassC* classCinstance, int gnr, int type) : ClassA(classCinstance);
```

should read:

```
ClassB(ClassC* classCinstance, int gnr, int type);
```